# JSON & Discord's WebHook

Tags: json, discord

Me and a friend are playing around with JSON, neither of us have touched it before so we're learning as we go along, but we've managed to make a bot type text into chat, with the help of IFTTT and Amazon's Echo Dot.

However, Discord allows users to use a text-to-speech feature with the command /tts.

```
{
    "content": "Hello World!"
}
```

We've done something on the lines of this to start off, which works as expected, but now we have to use a boolean to determine whether or not we want this to be read out via tts.

```
{
    "content": [{
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Hello World!",
        "tts": "true"
    }]
}
```

This throws up no errors, but the text isn't returned in the chat, nor is it spoken out loud at all. From [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-slackcompatible-webhook) you'll find the resource page for the webhook, and near the bottom of the page, you'll find a table containing the tts function.

If anyone has any idea on how to get this working it would be a real help since we don't know much JSON to start with anyone. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[It seems like a discord staff member already answered your questions](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/5mo3es/help_with_webhook_tts/)

You don't need an array for the content block,

```
{ 
    "content": "Hello World", 
    "tts": true 
}
```

would be fine